# What is the best data structure for fast dictionary search?

Tags: performance, search, dictionary

As far as I know, hash tables and double array tries are two of fastest data structures for searching a dictionary.  Are there any other data structures or algorithms that can beat them?

Answer (score 0):

Hash table need not always be a fast searching data structure. It really depends on how good your hashing function is. If your hashing function is not very good it could resolves multiple keys to map to similar index causing collision and make the hash table degenerate to O(n) run time.

Self Balancing trees are considered to be fast data structures as well as they guarantee O(log n)